# Table duplicate instead of replace

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I have this table, created throught JS, and it's connected with fullcalendar.
When I'm viewing a certain month (for example: May (*Maggio* in italian)) in my calendar and I click on a button it show this table, where it shows May (with 31 days): [image: modal]

But if I change month (for example, I go to June), this happens: [image: duplicate]

It actually print the correct table, but instead of replacing it (as I would like to do) it added under the old one

Can someone help me understand why it did this?

**This is my table code:**

```
function renderTable($targetTable, date, view, element ) {     

    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    var start = view.intervalStart._d;
    var end = view.intervalEnd.subtract(1, 'days');
    
    
    //prende mese e anno attualmente visualizzati e lo imposta come titolo del modal nell'HTML
    const months = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"];
   /*var d = new Date(start);
    var n = months[d.getMonth()]; */
    

    //calcola il numero dei giorni nel mese (30/31/28)
    let numberOfDaysInMonth = new Date(end).getDate(); // just get the last day

    //create the table header to display the month and date, and make is span all the days + the names column + the total column.
    let $tableHeader = $(`<tr><th colspan="${numberOfDaysInMonth+2}" style="text-align: center;">${months[start.getMonth()]} ${start.getFullYear()}</th></tr>`)

    //add header to our table
    $targetTable.find('thead').append($tableHeader);
    
    //Lets create a new empty table row to hold our heading and add our first column 
    let $header = $("<tr><td>Eventi</td>"); //this is using jQuery's method to create. anything starting $() is jQuery
    
    //Build the header
    //We're starting from 1 and counting up to the number of days
    for(let i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInMonth; i++) {
        let $dayCell = $(`<td class="days" style="width: 10%;">${i}</td></tr>`); // create a day cell with our day of month number in it.
        $header.append($dayCell); // Now we append our new day cell to our header.
    }
    //now add the Total cell.
    $header.append($('<td id="tot">Totale</td>'));
    
    //now our header is built, let's add it to our table....
    $targetTable.find('tbody').append($header);
    
    // now lets work on those columns....
    //This iterates (loops) through each row.  the `rowText` variable is updated to the next value from our array each time.
    rowData.forEach(rowText => {
     
        //Create a new row and set our text
        let $row = $(`${rowText}`);
     
        //now Javascript introduced a very nice string repeater we can use for our remaining cells.
        //this basically copies the string 1 more, than the number of days, to cater for our Totale column
        let $cells = $('<td id="hou" class="count"></td>'.repeat(numberOfDaysInMonth) + '<td class="totNum"></td>'); 
     
        // add these new cells to our row.
        $row.append($cells);
      
      //add our new row to the table
      $targetTable.find('tbody').append($row);      
    })      
}
```

---

**This is where I call my table function in JS:**

```
var date = new Date();
renderTable($('#table2'), date);
```

Comment: As far as I know you're appending the items to the targetTable without clearing the innerHTML first. If you clear the innerHTML first and then append your items it will not keep adding more and more tables but just replace them.

Comment: Can i ask you how I can do that? I new to JS and I'm trying to learn throught internet alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call empty(); on the target table it will clear all it's child elements.

```
function renderTable($targetTable, date, view, element ) {    
    // This line here
    
    $targetTable.find('thead').empty();
    $targetTable.find('tbody').empty();

    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    var start = view.intervalStart._d;
    var end = view.intervalEnd.subtract(1, 'days');
    
    
    //prende mese e anno attualmente visualizzati e lo imposta come titolo del modal nell'HTML
    const months = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"];
   /*var d = new Date(start);
    var n = months[d.getMonth()]; */
    

    //calcola il numero dei giorni nel mese (30/31/28)
    let numberOfDaysInMonth = new Date(end).getDate(); // just get the last day

    //create the table header to display the month and date, and make is span all the days + the names column + the total column.
    let $tableHeader = $(`<tr><th colspan="${numberOfDaysInMonth+2}" style="text-align: center;">${months[start.getMonth()]} ${start.getFullYear()}</th></tr>`)

    //add header to our table
    $targetTable.find('thead').append($tableHeader);
    
    //Lets create a new empty table row to hold our heading and add our first column 
    let $header = $("<tr><td>Eventi</td>"); //this is using jQuery's method to create. anything starting $() is jQuery
    
    //Build the header
    //We're starting from 1 and counting up to the number of days
    for(let i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInMonth; i++) {
        let $dayCell = $(`<td class="days" style="width: 10%;">${i}</td></tr>`); // create a day cell with our day of month number in it.
        $header.append($dayCell); // Now we append our new day cell to our header.
    }
    //now add the Total cell.
    $header.append($('<td id="tot">Totale</td>'));
    
    //now our header is built, let's add it to our table....
    $targetTable.find('tbody').append($header);
    
    // now lets work on those columns....
    //This iterates (loops) through each row.  the `rowText` variable is updated to the next value from our array each time.
    rowData.forEach(rowText => {
     
        //Create a new row and set our text
        let $row = $(`${rowText}`);
     
        //now Javascript introduced a very nice string repeater we can use for our remaining cells.
        //this basically copies the string 1 more, than the number of days, to cater for our Totale column
        let $cells = $('<td id="hou" class="count"></td>'.repeat(numberOfDaysInMonth) + '<td class="totNum"></td>'); 
     
        // add these new cells to our row.
        $row.append($cells);
      
      //add our new row to the table
      $targetTable.find('tbody').append($row);      
    })      
}
```

I think this should solve your issue if I understood you question correctly

Comment: I did found (before asking this question) the empty() function. The problem is that if I wrote that it doesnt rendere the table at all. Not event the first time. I'm gonna update with a screen

Comment: Could you show the function call aswell and where/how you're setting the variables you're passing as parameters?

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna added

Comment: Could you try the edit I made those two empty calls instead of one on $targetTable we call it on thead and tbody

Comment: Same as before, erased the table even the first time so doesnt show the table at all. I was thinking maybe putting in a loop, could be an asnwer?

Comment: Did that do it? If so it's because you're not creating the entire table in the function only the inner parts of the header and body. When I said to empty $targetTable it also removed the thead and tbody parts so when you call find('thead') it can't find it and won't append anything so oops.

Comment: I get what you were trying to do, and think is the right way. But the problem is that it remove the thead and tbody always, event the first time. So I never have a table. What i think I need is to let first check if the table is in fact empty or not, and in the second case to empty it with the code you gave me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

Basically where i call the function that build my table I added this:

```
//table2 is the ID of my table
var table = document.getElementById('table2');

//i check if the table is empty; if it is than I render the thead and tbody
if (table.rows.length == 0){
    var date = new Date();
    renderTable($('#table2'), date);        
}
//if not, before I delete whats inside and than I render it
else if(table.rows.lenght != 0){
    $("#table2 thead").empty();
    $("#table2 tbody").empty();
    var date = new Date();
    renderTable($('#table2'), date);
}
```